# What is the purpose of libParallelCompression in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, compression

I do data compresssion with [`libcompression.tbd`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/data_compression), which was introduced
in iOS 9.0. There appeared **`libParallelCompression.tbd`** in iOS 11.0. But I can't find any information about it, and library header looks like that:

```
symbols:         [ _BXDiff5, _BXPatch5, _BXPatch5InPlace, _BXPatchFile, _CachePatch, 
                       _DirectoryDiff, _DirectoryPatch, _ISparseArchiveStreamCreate, 
                       _ISparseArchiveStreamDestroy, _ISparseArchiveStreamRead, _PCompressFilter, 
                       _PackagePatch, _ParallelArchiveExtract, _ParallelArchiveGenerateBOM, 
                       _ParallelArchiveGenerateMSUBOM 
...
```

I have strong suspicion that `libParallelCompression` is for audio processing.

How to detect the purpose of `libParallelCompression.tbd`? 
Do you know compression libs for iOS, faster that `libcompression.tbd`?